# Need to hide text in UITextField while editing and should display another text

Tags: iphone

New to iOS development. Need help regarding `UITextField`  delegate methods.
my problem is I have `UITextField`

if i enter some "XYZ" text in textfield it should display some other text like which i want while i'm editing only it should done.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    [self.requestTextFiled setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:nil selector:@selector(checkingTheQuestion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];   
}

-(void)checkingTheQuestion
{    

}
```

I tried if by call checkingTheQuestion but I'm not able to do.
Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does " it should display some other text like which i want while i'm editing only it should done." mean ? If you are entering "XYZ" what do you want it to show ?

Comment: i created a NSString *string = @"PLease Tell me"; so while entering any text it should display this text there.

Comment: If i'm entering "XYZ" in a textfield i want to store the "XYZ" text in any string but while i am typing 'X' in XYZ it in a textfield it should show 'P' and if i enter 'Y' it should show 'l' in a textfiled like that. i need to display.

Comment: Even if you get it to work (which should not be too hard), this is almost certainly a bad idea from a user experience point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

is the method for you. You can use it as :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //Your code

    if([textField.text isEqualToString:@"xyz"])
    {
        textField.text = @"Text you want to set";
    }
}
```

This method is called when you type any character on keypad.